# How to get TimeStamp using logstash from Json file? There multiple date fields in the JSON

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash

I have my JSON input as follows which has date field and need to extract the date time field from Json,

```
{
  "Properties": {
         "Client Name": "Chubb",
         "Portfolio": "Chubb-Transfer"
  },
"Capture": [
         {
            "CaptureGUID": "caa1f5ba-1e93-4926-b3ac-e30d0d9d4cbb",
            "HTMLPath": "Captures\\C:\\",
            "ScreenName": "Amdocs CRM - ClearCallCenter - [Console]",
            "TimeStamp": "20170926110036"
          },
         {
            "CaptureGUID": "0faf6b54-999f-4bfd-b8d0-e81a589f9185",
            "HTMLPath": "Captures\\C:\\",
            "ScreenName": "Microsoft Excel - 1.0.1 1.0.6 1.0.8 Match 3.0.6 Hit NAIC Optimized.xlsx",
            "TimeStamp": "20170926105418"
          }
     ]
}
```

and My Logstash Config is as below, how to convert the string date ("TimeStamp": "20170926105418") to date format.Have updated with full Logstash file

```
input {
    file { 
        type => "json"
        path => "C:/ELK/data/Recordings/*.json"
        start_position => beginning
        codec => multiline {
           pattern => "^{"
           negate => "true"
           what => "previous"
           multiline_tag => "multi_tagged"
           max_lines => 30000
       }
    }
}
filter{
    date {
        match => ["Capture.TimeStamp", "yyyyMMddHHmmss"]
        target => "TimeStamp"
    }

    mutate { 
    replace => { "message" => "%{message}}" }
    gsub => [ 'message','\n','']
    }

    json { 
        source => "message" 
        remove_field => ["message"]
    }


}

output {
    elasticsearch {
    index => "test10"
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the date filter from logstash config file. Handle the date parsing while mapping the index. Below is the mapping for your use case.

```
PUT json
{
  "mappings": {
    "json": {
      "properties": {
        "Capture": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "CaptureGUID": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "HTMLPath": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "ScreenName": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "TimeStamp": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "yyyyMMddHHmmss"
            }
          }
        },
        "Properties": {
          "properties": {
            "Client Name": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "Portfolio": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No I have tried that it not even considering that , The ouput is as follows,                       {    "Properties" => {"Client Name"=> "Chubb",
         "Portfolio"=> "Chubb-Transfer"
  }, "Capture" => [ {           "CaptureGUID"=> "caa1f5ba-1e93-4926-b3ac-e30d0d9d4cbb",  "HTMLPath"=> "Captures\\C:\\", "ScreenName"=> docs CRM - ClearCallCenter - [Console]", "TimeStamp"=> 20170926110036"}]

Comment: Yes have pasted

Comment: Hi Thank you, where to put this in my Logstash config file.

Comment: No. this is index mapping, it is like "create table blah..." in terms of sql. Run this is in kibana but make sure you first delete existing mapping.

Comment: Yes i have tested it in Kibana directly it is working. But is there way in windows to automatically read a folder to detect json and start indexing which is like logstash.

Comment: You are doing it right. you are monitoring the entire Recordings folder for .json files. As soon as new files is saved it will get index in ES.

Answer (score 0):

Have solved by the following,

```
input {
    file { 
        type => "json"
        path => "C:/ELK/data/Recordings/*.json"
        start_position => beginning
        codec => multiline {
           pattern => "^{"
           negate => "true"
           what => "previous"
           max_lines => 30000
       }
    }
}
filter{

    mutate { 
    replace => { "message" => "%{message}}" }
    gsub => [ 'message','\n','']
    }

    json { 
    source => "message" 
    remove_field => ["message"]
    }

    date {
    match => ["[Capture][0][TimeStamp]", "yyyyMMddHHmmss"]
    target=> "[Capture][0]StartTime"
    timezone => "Africa/Lome"
    locale => "en" 
    }


}

output {
    elasticsearch {
    index => "test15"
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug } 
}
```